# Alignment not straight and rows don't span?

Tags: css, css-grid

I am stuck on two issues with my layout. 
*1)* The two `div`s in header and footer don't align up (just off slightly)
*2)* I am using `grid-areas` for my main content, but can't get it to span all the way down to the footer.

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/rEZwJY?editors=1100

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header header header header header header header"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer"
}

.header {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: header;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "logo nav"
}

.main {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 1em 0;
  grid-area: main;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: footer;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "legal links"
}

.logo {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.nav {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: content;
}

.newsletter {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: newsletter;
}

.legal {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: legal;
}

.links {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: links;
}

.grid div {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="nav">Navigation</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="newsletter">newsletter</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="legal">Legal</div>
    <div class="links">Links</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you define `grid-template-columns` or `grid-template-rows` you have to specify the same amount of units in your `grid-template-areas`!

```css
html, body { margin: 0; }

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas:
    "header"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "main"
    "footer";
  height: 100vh;
}

.header {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: header;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "logo nav";
}

.main {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 1em 0;
  grid-area: main;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(6, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter";
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: footer;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "legal links";
}

.logo {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.nav {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: content;
}

.newsletter {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: newsletter;
}

.legal {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: legal;
}

.links {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: links;
}

.grid div {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="nav">Navigation</div>
  </div>

  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="newsletter">newsletter</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="legal">Legal</div>
    <div class="links">Links</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hello again ) and thank you again, this worked! I am using grid-areas after what you said and works much better! You're so kind to help me out! Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

> The two divs in header and footer don't align up

it is caused by the width of the content varies, in this case because it depends on text length and the font and font sizes etc.

Also You didn't specify columns so here's what happens:

**The font here is `Times New Roman` default in chrome and font size is `16px`**

Say the container is `300px` wide the word `logo` takes `33.77px` and `navigation` takes `71.09px`

First sum up the lengths of the content

```
33.77 + 71.09 = 104.86000000000001
```

Second subtract it from the width of the container

```
300 - 104.86000000000001 = 195.14
```

Third Split it amongst the grid items in this case we 2

```
195.14 / 2 = 97.57
```

Fourth we add that to the length of each grid item thus the container will fill up

```
*logo* takes 97.57 + 33.7 = 131.34
*navigation* takes 97.57 + 71.09 = 168.66
*sum equals container's width* 168.66 + 131.34 = 300
```

Nice, How do we fix this ?

So How can we fix this by defining explicit even widths (just because you want the footer to align with the header for some reason), or we can define columns using `fr` units exactly like the other answer suggested, but keep in mind that the padding also affects the content's length.

```css
*, *:before, *:after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  width: 300px;
}

.header {
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas: 'logo nav';
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  grid-template-areas: 'legal links'
}

.logo {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.nav {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.legal {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: legal;
}

.links {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: links;
}

.container div {
  animation:anim 10s linear infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes anim{
0%{
padding: 0em;
}
100%{
padding: 3em;
}
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="nav">Navigation</div>
  </div>

  <div class="footer">
    <div class="legal">Legal</div>
    <div class="links">Links</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

---

> I am using grid-areas for my main content, but can't get it to span all the way down to the footer.

It's because you defined 12 rows yet you using just 5

```
grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);

grid-template-areas:
  "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
  "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
  "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
  "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
  "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
```

```css
.grid {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "header header header header header header header header header header header header"
    "main main main main main main main main main main main main"
    "footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer footer"
}

.header {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: header;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "logo nav"
}

.main {
  background-color: pink;
  margin: 1em 0;
  grid-area: main;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-template-areas:
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
    "sidebar content content content content newsletter"
}

.footer {
  background-color: pink;
  grid-area: footer;
  grid-gap: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas:
    "legal links"
}

.logo {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: logo;
}

.nav {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: nav;
}

.sidebar {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: sidebar;
}

.content {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: content;
}

.newsletter {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: newsletter;
}

.legal {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: legal;
}

.links {
  background-color: hotpink;
  grid-area: links;
}

.grid div {
  padding: 1em;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="header">
    <div class="logo">Logo</div>
    <div class="nav">Navigation</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="main">
    <div class="sidebar">sidebar</div>
    <div class="content">content</div>
    <div class="newsletter">newsletter</div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="footer">
    <div class="legal">Legal</div>
    <div class="links">Links</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

i would define a height rather than define 12 rows because you're just duplicating the height of content (*which is the text in this case*) 12 times

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I am on the latest version of Chrome on Mac and PC and if you look at where Nav begins and compare that with where Links start its off by a few pixels.

Comment: @EmmaStone see the explanation, i don't know why you want the header elements to align with the footer elements, in real world applications you don't see the header and footer at the same time.